# Check if NumericUpDown is empty

Tags: c#, numericupdown

How do I check whether the user left a `NumericUpDown` control empty, removing the value on it?
So I can reassign it a value of 0.

Comment: check the length of the variable - http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-length

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if(NumericUpDown1.Text == "")
{
     // If the value in the numeric updown is an empty string, replace with 0.
     NumericUpDown1.Text = "0";
}
```

Comment: Note that Visual studio won't show the "Text" property but you can type it anyway and it will compile.

Answer (score 8):

It might be useful to use the validated event and ask for the text property

```
private void myNumericUpDown_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myNumericUpDown.Text == "")
    {
        myNumericUpDown.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if the user deleted the content of the `numericUpDown` control, its value still remains.
`upDown.Text` will be "", but `upDown.Value` will be the previous valid value entered.
So my way to 'prevent' the user to leave the control empty, on the `onLeave` event, I set:

```
upDown.Text = upDown.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal d = 0 
if(decimal.TryParse(NumericUpDown1.Text, out d)
{

}
NumericUpDown1.Value = d;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((Control)this.nud1).Text))
{
  //null
}
else
{
  //have value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forbid empty value for `NumericUpDown`, just use this class. Its effect is that once the user tries to erase the control value with *select-all + backspace key*, the actual numeric value is set again. This is not really an annoyance since the user can still *select-all + type a numeric digit* to start editing a new numeric value.

```
  sealed class NumericUpDownEmptyValueForbidder {
     internal NumericUpDownEmptyValueForbidder(NumericUpDown numericUpDown) {
        Debug.Assert(numericUpDown != null);
        m_NumericUpDown = numericUpDown;
        m_NumericUpDown.MouseUp += delegate { Update(); };
        m_NumericUpDown.KeyUp += delegate { Update(); };
        m_NumericUpDown.ValueChanged += delegate { Update(); };
        m_NumericUpDown.Enter += delegate { Update(); };
     }
     readonly NumericUpDown m_NumericUpDown;
     string m_LastKnownValueText;

     internal void Update() {
        var text = m_NumericUpDown.Text;
        if (text.Length == 0) {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_LastKnownValueText)) {
              m_NumericUpDown.Text = m_LastKnownValueText;
           }
           return;
        }
        Debug.Assert(text.Length > 0);
        m_LastKnownValueText = text;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if(numericUpDown.Value == 0){

 MessageBox.Show(
   "Please insert a value.", 
   "Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
   MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation
 );

 return;

}
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.